# How to deal with string that contains "&" during the form post in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
Title=Nike+was+incorporated+on+&src=img/nike.png&body=mike&sulley+met+in
```

My serialized string looks something like this during the httppost. Modelbinder splits the querystring at every `&` symbol.For the above modelbinder recognises the querystring as

```
Title= Nike was incorporated on
Src= img/nike.png
body=mike
sulley= met in
```

But if you noticed the `body` shoud be `mike and sulley met in`.
How do i tell modelbinder that `sulley` is not a `key` but the remaining value of `body`?
I'm using mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ampersands must be encoded `body=mike%26sulley+met+in`

See URL data encoding in wikipedia / the rfc.

Comment: Entity-encoding is for example used in HTML, but not like this in HTTP.

Comment: He was right. I had to use encodeURIComponent(message) to encode the string. so & becomes %26